# Python logger code stopping code from executing

Tags: python, logging

The below code stops my class from running, could someone please tell me why.  From what I can tell it is the logger.FileHandler section but I don't understand why, I use the same code in a different script without issue.  I have checked the file location and it exists and the IIS server user has write access.

It is called using `logger.info(f'get_vlans({ip_address}, {int_len}, {type})')` and have confirmed all of the variables are suppling the correct values.

```
import logging
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = now.strftime("%m-%Y")

# create logger with the name 'gp_uccx_app'
logger = logging.getLogger('netweb_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# # create file handler
fh = logging.FileHandler(f'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/site1/python/custom/logs/log-{now}.txt')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter and add it to the handler
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Class code

```
class Netweb:


# Collects the vlans for all interfaces in the stack that have the line 'switchport access vlan' in the running config
def get_vlans(ip_address, int_len, type):
    logger.info(f'get_vlans({ip_address}, {int_len}, {type})')
    vlans = []
    try:
        reSearch = ''
        if int_len == 'long' and type == 'gigabitethernet':
            reSearch = "^interface GigabitEthernet\d\/0\/\d"
        elif int_len == 'long' and type == 'fastethernet':
            reSearch = "^interface FastEthernet\d\/\d"
        elif int_len == 'short' and type == 'gigabitethernet':
            reSearch = "^interface GigabitEthernet\d\/\d"
        elif int_len == 'short' and type == 'fastethernet':
            reSearch = "^interface FastEthernet\d\/\d"
        net_connect = ConnectHandler( device_type=platform, ip=ip_address, username=cisco_username, password=cisco_password )

        output = net_connect.send_command( 'show run | i (interface)|.(access vlan)' )
        net_connect.disconnect()

        output = output.splitlines()

        x = 0

        for out in output:
            if re.search( reSearch, out ):
                interface = out.split()
                interface = interface[ 1 ]
                if 'access vlan' in output[ x + 1 ]:
                    vlan = output[ x + 1 ].split( 'switchport access vlan' )[1].strip()
                else:
                    vlan = '1'
                vlans.append( [ interface, vlan ] )

            x = x + 1
            
        return vlans
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(e)
```

Comment: There's no class code here. Please post a [mre].

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Try relative file paths. In this example, use only `logs/logs-{now}.txt`

Comment: Added the method I am calling